# Mysql Join and Case Issues

Tags: mysql, left-join, case

I have the following Two tables..

```
table-1
|id| text1  | text2  |
----------------------
|1 | orange | banana |
|2 | banana | NULL   |
|3 | orange | NULL   |
|4 | papaya | orange |
|5 | papaya | papaya |
|6 | papaya | papaya |
|7 | mango| NULL   |

table-2
|id| id-table-1 |
-----------
|1 |   1  |
|2 |   3  |
|3 |   4  |
|3 |   6  |
|3 |   7  |
```

What I want is, only the id listed in table-2 left join should be calculated and shown. if text2 is not Null then must count the data as 1. But if the text2 is empty or null then count the text1 data as 1. the result should be like this.

if i say where text1 or text2 == banana, I must get the result like

```
name   count
banana  1
```

OR, Incase of orange the following..

```
name   count
orange  2
```

how do i achieve that? Need Help please?

Comment: What is idAg and id in table-2?

Comment: I just update the question, it is just is for table-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what you want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.text2, t1.text1) AS name,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `table-2` t2
LEFT JOIN `table-1` t1 ON t1.id = t2.`id-table-1`
GROUP BY name
```

Output:

```
name    count
banana  1
mango   1
orange  2
papaya  1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=7f09064e78cd31117a51547620048cc2)

Comment: @Barmar thanks, link added. Not sure how it managed not to insert the first time.